# O que há de errado neste procedimento ao salvar um formulário?

Tags: python, django

Possuo um formulário de cadastro e estou tentando salvar informações nele.

Ao tentar cadastrar, ele retorna um erro de formulário dizendo o e-mail já existe (mesmo cadastrando diferentes tipos de e-mail). Ou seja, ele esta salvando antes das verificações se o formulário é valido, porém não há nenhuma instrução esclarecendo isso.

```
class CadastroCreateView(CreateView):
    form_class = CadastroForm
    success_url = '/?cadastro=1'
    template_name = 'signup.html'
    model = Cadastro

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CadastroCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({
            'estados':U.STATE_CHOICES,
            'culturas':Cultura.objects.all(),
            'interesses': Topico.objects.all(),
        })
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Handles POST requests, instantiating a form instance and its inline
        formsets with the passed POST variables and then checking them for
        validity.
        """
        self.object = None
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)


        if (form.is_valid()):
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return HttpResponse('oi')
            return self.form_invalid(form)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        """
        Called if all forms are valid. Creates a Recipe instance along with
        associated Ingredients and Instructions and then redirects to a
        success page.
        """
        self.object = form.save()
        u = authenticate(username=self.object.email, password=self.object.senha)
        authlogin(self.request, u)
        return redirect('conteudos:home')


    def form_invalid(self, form):
        """
        Called if a form is invalid. Re-renders the context data with the
        data-filled forms and errors.
        """
        return self.render_to_response(
            self.get_context_data(form=form)
        )
```

Comment: Cara, se você precisa fazer um override de post, get, form_valid e invalid, reveja a sua ideia de utilizar class based view. Essa view ai pode ser bastante reduzida se tu for pra function based view.

Comment: E você pode remover essa implementação do seu post e testar, ela não está fazendo nada ai. Você pode deixar só o form_valid

Comment: Certo. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para "registro" de usuários temos a opção de utilizar o framework de autenticacao do django.
Este fw inclui os seguintes models:

- User: Model para usuarios com os campos principais:  username,
  password, email, first_name, last_name e is_active.
- group: Nomes dos grupos para categorização dos usuarios
- permission: Autoexplicativo

Para responder a pergunta, vamos desenvolver um exemplo no qual fazemos registros de usuários, aproveitando esse framework. Para focar no problema do email e tornar simples, vamos cadastrar somente "username" e seu email.

Vou relatar nessa resposta somente a estrategia de desenvolvimento do form, da view e das templates. Desenvolvi um exemplo completo que vc pode [baixar aqui](https://github.com/Sidon/sto-cadastro).

Primeiro vamos desenvolver nosso form, que utiliza o model User do FW de autenticação do django, como mencionado antes, nesse form incluiremos somente o username e o email.

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email')
```

Agora a nossa view (em core/views.py)

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import UserRegistrationForm

def create_account(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid():
            new_user = user_form.save(commit=False)
            new_user.save()
            return render(request, 'core/register_done.html', {'new_user': new_user})
    else:
        user_form = UserRegistrationForm()
    return render(request, 'core/register.html', {'user_form': user_form})
```

A view é bem simples. Se a for "chamada" por um GET, tenta renderizar a a template register.html, se chamada pelo POST e o form foi validado, ela vai tentar renderizar a template register_done.html, ambas da app core, vamos cria-las

core/registe.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="{% static "css/base.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Cadastro de usuários com email</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Criando uma conta</h1>
    <p>Digite os dados solicitados abaixo:</p>
    <form action="." method="post">
        {{ user_form.as_p }}
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p><input type="submit" value="Criar minha conta" </p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

core/register_done.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="{% static "css/base.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Cadastro de usuários com email</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Registro Efetuado</h1>
    <p>Para criar outra conta <a href="{% url "create_account" %}"> Clique aqui</a>  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Com isso voce consegue cadastrar emails em um model, através de um form. Se quiser pode extender o User do Django para outro model, como por exemplo um Profile. Para testar o codigo completo dessa solução, [clone o repositório no git-hub](https://github.com/Sidon/sto-cadastro)